# Best Practices Regarding Formatted Data in Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, bestpractice

We're currently setting up a new data extension for our orders, and the previous data extension was importing every column as TEXT. This means that every query we run must first CAST or CONVERT these columns before we can run certain functions on them.

Is there any harm in changing these from TEXT to their native formats, like DATETIME, DECIMAL, and NUMBER fields?

These values will be sent from SAP which has tight controls on data cleanliness. I don't foresee any issues with sending malformed data.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost impossible to foresee whether there would be any problems, as we can't see the raw data being imported, however, I would definitely test to check whether the data is being imported correctly by importing a CSV sample into the Data Extension directly before pointing your automations/API to the new Data Extension.